# Get the dispatched value from the Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get the stored value in Reducer State in my other `.js` file.

Below is Reducer -

```
const initialState = {
 filters: {
  name: '',
 },
};

export const EmployeeSummaryReducer = createSlice({
  name: 'EMP_SUMMARY',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
   SetFilters: (state, action) => {
     state.filters = action.payload;
   },
 }
});

 export const empSummaryState = (state) => state['EMP_SUMMARY'];

 export const {
  SetFilters,
 } = EmployeeSummaryReducer.actions;

 export default EmployeeSummaryReducer.reducer;
```

I am dispatching filters like -

```
dispatch(
  SetFilters({
    name: empName,
  }),
);
```

Here is the Store I am creating -

```
export const Store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    EMP_SUMMARY: EmployeeSummaryReducer,
  },
});
```

And trying to get the name from the reducer state as below -

```
import {
  empSummaryState,
} from '../Redux/EmployeeSummaryReducer'; 

const filters = useSelector(empSummaryState)?.filters;

console.log(filters?.name); // Here I am getting empty value.
```

Comment: What is the name of that slice in state when you create the store? *That's* what you need in the state selection path in the selector function. Can you [edit] to share how you've combined reducers and created the `store` object?

Comment: React is new for me. Currently whatever I have in my code I have put here. Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Is `empName` defined where you are dispatching the `SetFilters` action? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] so we can see all the code it doing between the UI and the store?

Comment: Yes. ```empName``` I am getting from UI and dispatching the ```SetFilters``` action.

Comment: Is `empName` a ***defined*** value though? Do you happen to have the redux dev-tools enabled and browser extension installed? You can inspect the store, the dispatched actions and each state update.

Comment: I have added a ```console.log('State :', current(state));``` in ```SetFilter``` and I could see the state is setting the value

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code you've shared. Could you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?